# Remove chapter number on algorithm numbers (scrbook)

Tags: numbering, chapters, koma-script, templates, algorithm2e

I write my bachelor thesis using a document class provided by our institute based on `scrbook`. I write pseudo-codes using `algorithm2e` which I put in the appendix since otherwise they would "interrupt" reading the text where I refer to them (they cover 4 pages).

My thesis has 7 chapters, excluding References and Appendix. The algorithms are numbered in their caption as `7.1`, `7.2` and so on. I want them to be numbered `1`, `2`, ...

After googling, I found out how to *add* chapter numbers to the captions, however, I didn't write any of this (by myself, at least).
How can I tell `algorithm2e` *not* to include the chapter numbers, as the appendix shouldn't be treated as part of my last chapter?

As chapter numbers may have been explicitly enabled in the document class I'm using: Which command(s) in the class file can be the problem? Note that all types of floats with captions (figures, theorems, ...) have a chapter number (but this is OK in general, except for my algorithms in the appendix).

I use the following options:

```
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Answer (score 2):

Without a MWE or your custom class, using the `chngcntr` package to reset the counter `\algocf@float` (indeed, a macro) after the last chapter may do the trick.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\makeatletter
\counterwithin{\algocf@float}{chapter}% maybe part of your custom class

\newcommand*{\algowithoutchap}{%
  \counterwithout{\algocf@float}{chapter}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

Some text.

\chapter*{Appendix}

\algowithoutchap

\begin{algorithm}
  \uIf{1}{if...}%
  \Else{else... \\ \If{1}{if...}}%
\caption{An algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```