# KOMA-script scrbook with single, unnumbered chapter

Tags: sectioning, numbering, koma-script, kaobook

I am using scrbook via [kaobook](https://github.com/fmarotta/kaobook) and I would like to make a document that contains a single chapter, unnumbered and unnamed. This probably means I shouldn't be using `scrbook` to begin with, but I'd like to make a document that is in the same style as another that will have multiple chapters, numbered and named.

```tex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter

\section{Introduction}
We will be brief.

\section{Details}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{
        A figure caption
    }
    \label{fig-1}
\end{figure}

There is no information in Figure~\ref{fig-1}.

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

and I would basically like to remove the `0.` from all references and headings. So the MWE would produce a figure numbered `1`, not `0.1`.

I'm hoping there's a straightforward way to get this done. This document will never have more than one chapter in it, so I would not mind a solution that would e.g. produce two figures called `1` if they are the first figure in two different chapters. If I can literally supress the `0.` prefix of the labels, that would be enough.

I noticed `\chapappifchapterprefix` mentioned in [kaobook.cls](https://github.com/fmarotta/kaobook/blob/b26491ef4a533f4920b8141d345d90b931436e4a/kaobook.cls#L117-L127), but I believe that refers to e.g. "Chapter" (related to [Custom chapter prefix text in KOMA-Script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489046/custom-chapter-prefix-text-in-koma-script))

Related but different question: [How to use unnumbered chapters with KOMA-script?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193767/how-to-use-unnumbered-chapters-with-koma-script)

Comment: Related answers:

1. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82606/remove-chapter-number-on-algorithm-numbers-scrbook

2. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87777/in-a-chapter-how-do-i-remove-chapter-numbers-from-figures-and-add-the-title-to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `\counterwithout` directive:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{mwe}
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\begin{document}
\mainmatter

\section{Introduction}
We will be brief.

\section{Details}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{
        A figure caption
    }
    \label{fig-1}
\end{figure}

There is no information in Figure~\ref{fig-1}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! If I have tables, algorithms, and other kinds of floats generally, I suppose I need to use the `\counterwithout` directive (which if I understand correctly, is defined by LaTeX) for each float environment?

Comment: For tables, certainly. For other environments with a counter, it depends on whether they're numbered per chapter or not. For instance, some document classes number theorems continuously for the whole document.

Answer (score 0):

I have added an unnamed and unnumbered `\chapter` to your MWE and changed the numbering schemes.

```
% anonchapprob.tex  SE 599268

\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter*{}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}

\section{Introduction}
We will be brief.

\section{Details}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{
        A figure caption
    }
    \label{fig-1}
\end{figure}

There is no information in Figure~\ref{fig-1}.

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

I hope I have interpreted your desire correctly.